# socket.io not connecting to client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, next.js

I am trying to emit a data to client via socket.io in next.js setup.But i dont get any data via it.

Below is my `server.js` code

```
    const app = require('express')()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const nextApp = next({ dev })
const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler()

// socket.io server
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('a user is connected')
  socket.broadcast.emit('now', {
    message: 'Hello'
  })
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected')
  })
})

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return nextHandler(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

when a user is connected it console logs `a user is connected` its working fine.

into my `_app.js` file i have included socket.io as instructed in next.js example: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-socket.io/pages/_app.js

Here is my _app.js file

```
    import App from 'next/app'
import React from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps ({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return { pageProps }
  }
  state = {
    socket: null
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    // connect to WS server and listen event
    const socket = io()
    this.setState({ socket })
  }

  // close socket connection
  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.state.socket.close()
  }

  render () {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
    return <Component {...pageProps} socket={this.state.socket} />
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

Main problem is In index.js file.Below is that file

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

class ChatOne extends Component {
  // init state with the prefetched messages
  state = {
    message: ''
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.socket.on('now', data => {
      this.setState({
        message: data.message
      })
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.message}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ChatOne
```

And after launch i am getting this error.I am asking this question to about the error of this question

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your first render of `<App />` won't have `this.state.socket` as that isn't set until it has mounted.

```
render () {
  const { socket } = this.state;

  if(!socket) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

  return <Component {...pageProps} socket={socket} />
}
```

Comment: Now the error is not showing.But socket is not receiving the message in index.js

Comment: looking at the docs, it seems `io()` takes a server address: `const socket = io('http://localhost');`